# How to handle User login service to get user info and logout state

Tags: angular

I am trying to add logout element to menu after user logins from '/login' to dashboard '/',

First,I tried adding auth service to dashboard component and update user variable on Component Initialisation (ngOnInIt) like this

```
    this.authService.getUser().subscribe(
       (data) => {
         if (data !== null) {
           this.username = data.local.username;
         }
       });
```

but my root component does not execute ngOnInit after redirecting from '/login' page, hence my username is not retrieved also.

Second time, I tried change detection with Observable, making `username` variable Observable in auth Service

```
user$: Observable<string> = this.getUser().map( data => {
  if (data !== null) {
   return data.local.username;
  }
 });

getUser() {
return this.http.get('/api/user')
  .catch( (error: any) => {
    return Observable.throw( error.toString() || ' :server error');
});
```

}

and in my dashboard I Injected this auth service and called `*ngIf="authService.user$ | async"`

But my result was same, i had to reload my page both time to get logout string displayed inside menu.

It's my first personal project with angular, please spare me any noobie mistake, and take time to enlighten me with explaination.
Thank you

Comment: @chayasan there's no error log, here is my gist

https://gist.github.com/techdiary/ec7096e27749dca8ea380b42f0787415

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the docs, which explains how to communicate through a service: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

in short, create an Observable, use a Subject:

```ts
private user = new Subject();
public user$ = this.user.asObservable();
```

When you receive your user from the backend, call `next` on your observable:

```ts
this.authService.login(val.email, val.password)
  .subscribe((result) => {
    console.log('User Logged in as: ', result);
    this.authService.user.next(result) // add this!
    //....
 });
```

And in your dashboard you just listen to changes:

```ts
constructor(...) {
  this.user$ = this.authService.user$;
}
```

and in template:

```ts
<ng-container *ngIf="user$ | async">
 ....
</ng-container>
```

With this you have to remember that this does not persist on page refreshes, so you might want to consider using `localStorage` combined, or then look to other options to store state.

Comment: Thank a lot @AJt_82 and is `localStorage` updated both at login and logout method? and another question that rather if it's a more convenient  way to use observer in template directly:
`*ngIf="authService.user$ | async"`, won't this do same as declaring it in constructor to a var?

Comment: Yeah, it'll do the same. I just like to keep template just with "simple variables" and handle else in component. But it's just a matter of preference, you do what you feel like! :) As for the `localStorage` You need to update the `localStorage` yourself, using `setItem`, `getItem` based on logged in status... You can combine it with the observable.

Comment: You can also look into ngrx-store together with ngrx-store-localstorage (or similar to manage app state)

Comment: as user is a private property, how can it be accessed, do we have to create another method in Service to load user data or multi-casting from login will work fine with session storage? and dude your cats are awesome

Comment: Thanks, yes, my kitties are awesome :P `user` is private for that reason to protect object mutability. You can add a method in service which you can access to set changes, like `setUser(user){this.user.next(user)}`. This then broadcasts the event to all components that are subscribing :)

Comment: I did the same thing, and it's not working now.. Here's my gist:https://gist.github.com/techdiary/dcd7b78dac97bedca7174d5e54f1ce35 
also i have my server on ngrock now for 10-15 min if you want to see it: https://7b352637.ngrok.io
well i appreciate your effort to help me, thank you.

Comment: Your code should look like something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umctpw?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: i implemented it and it's not working.. i'll contact you after learning its working more.
Thank you

Comment: Very nice solution

Answer (score 0):

Look like you could use [routing guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards),  [resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) or authorisation guard. Resolver example given below: This resolver, helps you to get user data before navigating into new route dashboard.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<User> {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    }

    public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<User> {
        return this.http.get('/api/user')
            .map(r => r.json() as User)
            .toPromise()
            .catch(e => this.handleError(e));
    }

    private handleError(e: Response): void {
        this.router.navigate(["/error" , e.status]);
    }
}
```

Configure resolver for component.

```
path:"dahsboard"
component: DashboardComponet,
resolve: {user: UserResolver }
```

In Dashboard component sunscribe to route and access the user detail

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            let user: User= this.route.snapshot.data.User;

        });
    }
```

Comment: yes, i can use that too or also http Interceptor but, I want to know my question answer to understand Change Detection better( even i have listened many post on this topic, sad:( )